# Laravel 5.8 и методы фиксирования изменений

Tags: php, laravel

В стандартном методе `update` в типичном котроллере есть строка обновление `$users->update($request->all());` мне предстоит решить задачу фиксирования изменений, полазив по документации [документация](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html) я набрёл на интересный метод `getChanges()` который показывает какие поля изменились, выше есть метод `getDirty()` как я понял показывает какие данные были до изменения последней синхронизации, я их стал использовать вот так `$users->getChanges();` после `$users->getDirty();`  ***getChanges*** нормально отработал, а вот ***getDirty*** был пуст, я понял что нету синхронизации и я сделал вот так
`$users->syncChanges(); 
$users->update($request->all());
$users->getChanges();
$users->getDirty();`
При этом getDirty снова пуст. Как правильно фиксировать изменения чтобы можно было реализовать запись например запись была изменена name: Ivan => Igor

Comment: UPD вынес в модель чтобы получить return $this->getDirty(); так же пусто

Comment: Попробуйте вызвать `getDirty` до сохранения записи.